# How can I set a default width for elements in a row, but have that width reduce when more elements are added?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

When there are 4 or more items I would like there to be 4 items per row and each item having a min width of 250px.

But when there are 3 or less items I would like those items to fit on a single row and each item should have a max width of 345px.

I have the following css classes applied:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: calc(100%/4);
  max-width: 345px;
}
```

This results in each item having a width of 345px no matter what. When there are 4 or more items I get three items per row each having 345px width. When there are 3 items or less I get a single row and each item having 345px.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

3 items or less: Single row. Each item having 345px max width.
4 items or more: Multiple rows with 4 items per row. Each item having 250px min width.

**NOTE**: Not sure if this changes anything, but the page is divided into 12 columns. And the items mentioned here appear on columns 2 through 8.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need some more flex properties, see snippet:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  outline: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

`flex-basis` provides the base size for each item, while `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` allow them to adjust to the available width. It could also be written with a shortcut

```
flex: 1 1 25%;
```

Comment: See how with your solution item 9 grows to fill the entire row? How can I have item 9 be the same size as items 1 through 8 as well?

Comment: I'm not clear with all the cases here. What should be the width when there's only 1 item? 2 items? 3 items? And when there're 1, 2 or 3 items in the last row?

Comment: Width should always be 345px. But if there are 4 or more items then width should be 250px for all items (also, 4 items per row).

Comment: @infiniteloop I'm not convinced that what you are asking is possible with pure CSS, because currently CSS selectors goes only forward - you can't style an element based on what comes after it or inside it. I tried to go hacky with this but failed to achieve exactly what you've asked. (Also, why 345px? 3 times 345 aren't even the same as 4 times 250)

Comment: I appreciate the help. It turns out that the cards don't have to be exactly 345px and 250px. But instead that the max width be 345px and the min width be 250px. It is required that at most 4 cards fit on a row before they start wrapping to the next row.

Comment: "at most 4 cards in a row" meaning that if the container is 2000px then the 5th element would go to the next line even though there is still a lot of empty room?